# How to convert a slice of 4 bytes to a rune? In Go

Tags: byte, go

I have the in-memory representation of a rune

```
key := make([]byte, 4)
```

Now, how to convert it to a rune?

Comment: I supposed in my answer that your "in-memory representation" is based on an UTF-8 encoding. Is that right ?

Comment: I'm using the slice "key" to read a key preesed: syscall.Read(fd, key)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a dedicated [DecodeRune](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRune) function :

> **func DecodeRune(p []byte) (r rune, size int)**
>
> DecodeRune unpacks the
>   first UTF-8 encoding in p and returns the rune and its width in bytes.
>   If the encoding is invalid, it returns (RuneError, 1), an impossible
>   result for correct UTF-8.

So you just have to import `"unicode/utf8"` and do

```
r, _ := utf8.DecodeRune(key)
```